# Oracle: ORA-01408: such column list already indexed

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME
(
  ID VARCHAR2(100) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  A_ID VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  B_ID VARCHAR2(100),
  C_ID INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT FK_C_NOTE FOREIGN KEY (C_ID) REFERENCES C(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_A_NOTE FOREIGN KEY (A_ID) REFERENCES A(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_B_NOTE FOREIGN KEY (B_ID) REFERENCES B(ID)
);
```

And I have tried to apply the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_FK_A_TABLE_NAME on SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME(A_ID) tablespace TS_SCHEMA_NAME_DATA;
CREATE INDEX IDX_FK_C_TABLE_NAME on SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME(C_ID) tablespace TS_SCHEMA_NAME_DATA; --Fails
CREATE INDEX IDX_FK_B_TABLE_NAME on SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME (B_ID) tablespace TS_SCHEMA_NAME_DATA; --Fails
```

But when I try to create the last two indexes I get:

> ORA-01408: such column list already indexed

Why is this? Are these indexes created automatically?

---

If I try:

```
SELECT INDEX_NAME FROM ALL_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NOTE';
```

I get:

```
INDEX_NAME
----------
IDX_FK_A_TABLE_NAME
SYS_C0044692561
```

Comment: No the indexes are not created automatically.  I just created tables A, B, C and then ran your create statements without any error (after adjusting schema and tablespace names).  Could it be that there is another table called NOTE that is not in schema "SCHEMA"?

Comment: Wouldn't that cause the 'create table' to fail?

Comment: @Ed0906 - tables with the same name can exist in multiple schema. You've only specified the schema for the table creation (or at least, that's all you've shown). You *may* be creating the table and indexes in different schemas, if your current schema (not the one you specified) already had a table with that name. But your ALL_INDEXES query suggests that isn't the case.

Comment: Well your `create table` specifies **SCHEMA**.NOTE, whereas your `create index` statements don't.  So if you are not connected as SCHEMA, or if there is a synonym called NOTE then "NOTE" without the SCHEMA prefix could point to a different table.

Comment: I tried changing the index script to use SCHEMA.NOTE but that still fails

Comment: Do you have an access to `dba_indexes` and `dba_tables`?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: What about `SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NOTE';`

Comment: That just brings back the single table

Comment: @AlexPoole: but wouldn't the error be "*name is already used by an existing object*" then?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - only if the index name was also the same as one in the current schea? I think that whole idea is ruled out anyway by the subsuequent edits, as it's still apparently happening with everything qualified. (My guess now is that the actual issue is a mistake that's been hidden by the obfuscation...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double check you indexed columns by querying ALL_IND_COLUMN (or DBA_IND_COLUMNS if you have acess). It will show you what table columns are indexed by which index.

```
SELECT c.index_owner, c.index_name, c.table_owner, c.table_name, c.column_name, c.column_position
  FROM all_ind_columns c
 WHERE c.table_owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
       AND c.table_name = 'NOTE'
 ORDER BY c.index_owner, c.index_name, c.column_position;
```

On a site note, When you are creating your indexes you're not prefixing them with a schema owner (CREATE INDEX SCHEMA.IDX_FK_A_TABLE_NAME ...). That means they're being created in your current schema. On the other hand, it's probably not related to the error you are facing.